# updateOrCreate() updating database using index

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a submit and update function for my form and in that form, the user can choose to add an additional row of inputs. These inputs will be saved in a new row, basically, one user can have several rows in the database. I have a problem with the update function, where if the user originally has two rows answered, in the update function if they still fill in two rows, both of the rows in the database will be updated, however, only the first row is getting updated. I tried accessing the key for the arrays and updating based on the array keys but it doesn't work.

Here is my whole controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Livewire\Field;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\Constant;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Application;

use App\Models\Model1;
use App\Models\Model2;
use App\Models\Model3;
use App\Models\Model4;

use Livewire\Component;
use DB;

class ModelComponent extends Component
{
    public $i = 1;
    public $updateMode = false;
   
    public $model2Rows = [];
    public $model4Rows = [];    

    public $showDiv1 = false;
    public $showDiv2 = false;
    public $showDiv3 = false;
    public $showDiv4 = false;

    public $m1_field;
    public $m1_field2;

    public $m2_field;
    public $m2_field2;

    public $m3_field;
    public $m3_field2;

    public $m4_field;
    public $m4_field2;

    public function openDiv($divNum)
    {
        if($divNum == 1) {
            $this->showDiv1 =! $this->showDiv1;
        } else if($divNum == 2) {
            $this->showDiv2 =! $this->showDiv2;
        } else if($divNum == 3) {
            $this->showDiv3 =! $this->showDiv3;
        } else if($divNum == 4) {
            $this->showDiv4 =! $this->showDiv4;
        }
    }   

    public function addMoreModel2Rows($i)
    {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->model2Rows , $i);
    }

    public function addMoreModel4Rows($i)
    {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->model4Rows , $i);
    }   
    
    public function removeModel2Rows($i)
    {
        unset($this->model2Rows[$i]);
    }

    public function removeModel4Rows($i)
    {
        unset($this->model4Rows[$i]);
    }
        
    public function submit()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        
        $application = Application::create([
            'app_type_id' => 1,
            'approval_status_id' => 1
        ]);
        
        $application->users()->save($user);

        $rules = [];   
        $validatedData = [];     
        
        if($this->showDiv1){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm1_field' => 'required',
                'm1_field2' => 'required',
            ]);
        }
        
        if($this->showDiv2){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm2_field.0' => 'required',
                'm2_field2.0' => 'required',
                'm2_field.*' => 'required',
                'm2_field2.*' => 'required',
            ]);                
        }
            
        if($this->showDiv3){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm3_field' => 'required',
                'm3_field2' => 'required',
            ]);
        }
                
        if($this->showDiv4){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm4_field.0' => 'required',
                'm4_field2.0' => 'required',
                'm4_field.*' => 'required',
                'm4_field2.*' => 'required',
            ]);
        }

        $validatedData = $this->validate($rules);

        if($this->showDiv1){
            Model1::create([
                'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                'm1_field' => $validatedData['m1_field'],
                'm1_field2' => $validatedData['m1_field2'],
            ]);
        }

        if($this->showDiv2){
            foreach ($this->m2_field as $key => $value){                
                Model2::create([
                    'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                    'm2_field' => $validatedData['m2_field'][$key],
                    'm2_field2' => sanitize_money($validatedData['m2_field2'][$key]),
                ]);
            }
        }

        if($this->showDiv3){
            Model3::create([
                'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                'm3_field' => $validatedData['m3_field'],
                'm3_field2' => $validatedData['m3_field2'],
                ]);
        }

        if($this->showDiv4){
            foreach ($this->m4_field as $key => $value){                
                Model4::create([
                    'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                    'm4_field' => $validatedData['m4_field'][$key],
                    'm4_field2' => sanitize_money($validatedData['m4_field2'][$key]),
                ]);
            }
        }
        
        $user->save();        
        
        alert('success','Your details are saved.');
        
        return redirect()->route('website.landing');
        
    }
    
    public function update()
    {
        // get user info in session        
        $user = auth()->user();

        $i = 0;

        $model2 = Model2::where('user_id', $user->user_id)->get();
        $model4 = Model4::where('user_id', $user->user_id)->get();
        
        $rules = [];   
        $validatedData = [];     
        
        if($this->showDiv1){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm1_field' => 'required',
                'm1_field2' => 'required',
            ]);
        }
        
        if($this->showDiv2){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm2_field.0' => 'required',
                'm2_field2.0' => 'required',
                'm2_field.*' => 'required',
                'm2_field2.*' => 'required',
            ]);                
        }
            
        if($this->showDiv3){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm3_field' => 'required',
                'm3_field2' => 'required',
            ]);
        }
                
        if($this->showDiv4){

            $rules = array_merge($rules, [
                'm4_field.0' => 'required',
                'm4_field2.0' => 'required',
                'm4_field.*' => 'required',
                'm4_field2.*' => 'required',
            ]);
        }

        $validatedData = $this->validate($rules);

        if($this->showDiv1){
            
            EmploymentDetail::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'user_id' => $user->user_id,
            ],
            [
                'm1_field' => $validatedData['m1_field'],
                'm1_field2' => $validatedData['m1_field2'],
            ]);
        }

        if($this->showDiv2){
            foreach ($this->m2_field as $key => $value){           
                $partTime[$key]->updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                ],
                [
                    'm2_field' => $validatedData['m2_field'][$key],
                    'm2_field2' => sanitize_money($validatedData['m2_field2'][$key]),
                ]);
            }
        }

        if($this->showDiv3){
            Model3::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'user_id' => $user->user_id,
            ],
            [
                'm3_field' => $validatedData['m3_field'],
                'm3_field2' => $validatedData['m3_field2'],
            ]);
        }
        
        if($this->showDiv4){
            foreach ($this->m4_field as $key => $value){
                if(!empty($model4[$i])){
                    $model4[$i]->updateOrCreate(
                    [
                       'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                    ],
                    [
                       'm4_field' => $validatedData['m4_field'][$key],
                       'm4_field2' => sanitize_money($validatedData['m4_field2'][$key]),
                    ]);
                 } else {
                    Model4::create([
                       'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                       'm4_field' => $validatedData['m4_field'][$key],
                       'm4_field2' => sanitize_money($validatedData['m4_field2'][$key]),
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }    
        
        alert('success','Your income are updated.');
        return redirect()->route('borrower.joint_declaration');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $income_informations = DB::table('income_informations')->get();
        $showDiv1 = $this->showDiv1;
        $showDiv2 = $this->showDiv2;
        $showDiv3 = $this->showDiv3;
        $showDiv4 = $this->showDiv4;
        

        return view('livewire.model-component',
            [
                'income_informations' => $income_informations,
                'showDiv1'=>$showDiv1,
                'showDiv2'=>$showDiv2,
                'showDiv3'=>$showDiv3,
                'showDiv4'=>$showDiv4,
            ]);
    }

}
```

I created a variable to store the arrays because I realized that if I simply use the model name and then do updateOrCreate() it will probably only update the first one. But the result of that update function is that it updates the first row in the database, then creates a new row for the additional row, but I want it to update the other rows in the database instead.

For more context, I followed through this [tutorial](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-livewire-dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields) for the adding input fields and saving function. Now I have trouble trying to do the update function.

Comment: show us input data and `$this->input_field`, maybe you should provide whole controller? and in the `update` method you have strange begavior when you call `$user->user_id` and later `auth()->user()->user_id`

Comment: @OlD.Castor just updated the whole controller into the code. I just realized the strange behaviour and corrected them accordingly. To note, both model2 and model4 are having the same problem, and I am just trying to do the solution in model4, thus explaining why model2 is a bit different than model4

Comment: You have `$user = auth()->user()`, and then you do `$user->user_id`, that doesn't look right. Should be `$user->id`?

Comment: Also you should consider using better variable names, typically using numbers like that will just confuse and cause havoc.

Comment: @Qirel my user_id is saved as user_id in database, so I'm just calling the user_id with the name it is stored

Comment: @Qirel my variables name arent that, i modified it for posting it in public because its a rather private repo, so i changed it for the sake of posting in publicly

Comment: Ok, just keep in mind that if you're not showing the actual code, it can happen that the actual issue is "lost in translation" and therefore overlooked. Also, there's a lot of code here, if possible, you should try to isolate it and only post relevant pieces of it.

Comment: I get that the user-id field on the relations are called that, but in the users table as well?

Comment: @Qirel yeah i actually only posted a snippet of the code but someone asked if I could just post the whole controller so I did. would you want me to update it to smaller chunks on code instead? also yeap in users table the name is user_id as well

Comment: Hmm, why are you using `updateOrCreate()`, and not just `update()`, with a `where()`? Using `updateOrCreate()` is only intended for a single row.

Comment: @Qirel because in the update function, there might be cases where users selected a new section to fill in, so it creates a new row if it was previously empty. and for the where, because in these two specific sections, users can have more than one row in the table, so I wanted to update all of these rows which is why I tried using array keys, but it only updated my first row

Comment: Aha, I see. Well, then you need a different approach, because `updateOrCreate()` needs to target a unique record, it can therefor only update 1 record. Since your user ID is the only thing passed, and it's not unique, you can't use it. Think of the attributes to the first argument of `updateOrCreate()` as the fields on a table which has a unique constraint on it.